# can't find my maven artifacts

Tags: maven, m2eclipse

I'm working in eclipse and I have a problem that I can't `import` my personal java libraries.

I created the libraries and 'installed' them into my local maven repo (using `mvn install`). This created a subdirectory related to the 'version' name that was in the POM file from when I ran the command. Which seemed fine.

So in this directory there where the usual jar files and other stuff.

When I released this file I manually changed the name of the version in the POM. going from 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT to 0.0.1-RELEASE

This seems to have worked as I would have expected.

However I can't seem to find import the new release jar.

Using the `maven repositories` browser in eclipse I can see that the new artifact is in the 'local' repository.

I try to add the dependency in the following methods:

- Select the main project -> Maven -> add dependency.

This adds the dependency details into the pom but with a type value detail of `<type>pom.lastUpdated</type>`

- Select the project pom.xml file -> Maven -> add dependency.

This time the artifact for the 0.0.1-RELEASE is `greyed out` I can select it, but I guess nothing is actually happening.
The original 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT it selectable, and if I use this I do not have a `<type>` detail in the pom.

I don't understand why there is a difference in the RELEASE and SNAPSHOT artifacts, as they have both been generated in the same way, and clearly they are both visible in the browser, the contents of the directory on disk are the same. The file names and contents are identical with the exception of the word RELEASE or SNAPSHOT.

I know that I can simply add in the RELEASE jar to my build path, but this seems to be a ridiculous thing to have to do if I intend to use maven (or do I need to do this).

I don't want to use an external repo for storing my artifacts, and I'm not too keen to go to the trouble of installing nexus (or similar) on my local machine (just because I've had trouble with it in the past).

What am I missing so as I can get my maven project to see my local repository and all its artifacts.

Thanks in advance.

David

ps I've already tried things such as `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` which definitely pulled in / updated all the local jar dependencies.

Comment: To install your project you have to use `mvn install` and not `mvn package`

Comment: @khmarbaise must appologise. I did use `mvn install` I've edited the question.

Comment: Maven treats snapshots differently.

Comment: @JimmyT. clearly, but how, and why isn't the `mvn install` working when I've modified the pom accordingly.

Comment: Your approach is not completely clear to me, but I would suggest (after deleting the content of your local repository): 1. Use mvn install to install your external jar with correct artifactId, version etc. 2. Set a dependency to it with <type>jar</type> 3. Recompile.

Answer (score 0):

So I've managed to work around my problem.

As such this solution is ridiculous, and breaks all the purpose of maven.

So I found (from running maven from the cli) that there was an error in the parent of the project I was attempting to use.

The parent was missing a direct link to the scm plugin (version error).

Once I solved this problem, I then returned to the sub project, and got a lot of errors from missing stuff from the parent.
Essentially it was not 'seeing' all the log4j dependencies.

The solution (well non-solution really).
Add all the log4j dependencies to the sub project.
Edit in SCM and surefire test plugins (as it also started to fail the test code due to missing junit).

So this is great.

I have to define all my dependencies on log4j and in my sub / child project's pom.xml file.
I also need to define them all in my parent's pom.

As it then still refused to run tests in my new project (that used the above as a dependency), and refused to find log4j also. I then decided to add all of these as dependencies for my current project.

Great.
I thought the whole point of maven was I could define my dependency on log4j in my my logging library that I use (which is the dependency), and then it would 'automagically' pull in all the required from this dependency.

Clearly not.

As stated at the start. This is NOT AN ANSWER it is a crazy work around.

My logging library that I use should be able to define its own requirement on a specific log4j version (such as moving from log4j to log4j2), and then when I include this as a maven dependency any change to the required dependency should be seen automatically.

But No :  I have to import the dependency on log4j in my other projects also. So now if I had updated my logging library from log4j to log4j2 I would need to go to all my project that use this library and update their pom's to ensure that I have the correct version of log4j.

Seems the whole point of maven has just been lost!

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong!

David.

Comment: It would help if you can give a link to your project cause what you have written does not related to your described problems...So i assume you have other problems or general understanding issues with Maven...

Comment: @khmarbaise I am sure I have other problems with maven in general. I'm quite new to it, so it wouldn't suprise me. I must admit I was rather irked when I wrote the above! I thought that including a set of libraries in my current project would 'automatically' bring in all the required dependencies for that set of libraries (as they are set in the pom). However it seems that this isn't the case. I also get the impression I'm constantly re-creating a local maven repository, to force the update of the information.